# マルチモニタで各々違うスケーリングを利用していると次回起動時にウィンドウ位置がずれる

Tags: emeditor

マルチモニタを利用している際、各々違うスケーリングをしていると次回起動時にウィンドウのサイズが再現できておらずおかしくなる。

再現方法
１．モニタを左から順に1,2として以下の設定を行う
　　１：スケーリング125%
　　２：スケーリング100%
２．EmEditorのウィンドウ開始位置をモニタ１の左右位置：中央、上下位置：上部、ウィンドウ終了位置をモニタ１の左下とする
３．EmEditorを終了する
４．EmEditorを起動する
上記手順でEmEditorのウィンドウ開始位置はOKだが、終了位置の右がモニタ２に食い込み、下が画面下より下にめり込む

Comment: EmEditor のバージョンはいくつでしょうか? 最新版でない場合、最新版にしてお試しください。ご質問にあるEmEditorのウィンドウ開始位置、終了位置の意味がわからないのですが、どういう意味でしょうか? EmEditorはタブを有効 ([ウィンドウ] メニュー) にしてお使いでしょうか? できれば画面図を載せていただけるとわかりやすいと思います。

Comment: バージョンはVersion 19.9.4で、タブは有効です。EmEditorのウィンドウ開始位置はそのままの意味で画面上でEmEditorのウィンドウの左上の座標、終了位置は右下の座標です。環境としてはマルチスクリーンで各々スケーリングが違う状態とし（双方100%のときは次回起動時は正しく同じ位置・サイズでウィンドウが開かれます）、EmEditorのウィンドウを右側のスクリーンの右半分のサイズにして終了し、再度EmEditorを起動するとウィンドウの左上の位置は同じ位置で起動するのですが、右下の位置が大きくずれてしまい、右はスクリーン２にめり込み、下は画面下より更に下の位置まで開いています。現象から察するとスクリーン1がスケーリング125%、スクリーン2がスケーリング100%だとすると、ウィンドウサイズを前回終了時のサイズx1.25倍して起動しているように見えます。

Answer (score 1):

コメントを追加できないため、こちらに書かせていただきます。

「ウィンドウ開始位置はそのままの意味で画面上でEmEditorのウィンドウの左上の座標、終了位置は右下の座標」だとすると、ご質問の「EmEditorのウィンドウ開始位置をモニタ１の左右位置：中央、上下位置：上部、ウィンドウ終了位置をモニタ１の左下とする」は、「左下」ではなく「右下」の間違いではないでしょうか?

お使いの Windows は、Windows 10 でしょうか? Windows 10 だとすると、Windows 10 は Version 1607 (Build 14393) 以上に更新されていますでしょうか? これ未満の Windows 10 または Windows 7、8.1 をお使いだと、残念ながら、スケーリングの異なるマルチ モニターには対応していない可能性があります。できれば、最新の Windows 10 に更新してご利用ください。

Windows 10 Version 1607 (Build 14393) 以上でも問題が発生している場合は、こちらで問題が再現できないため、もう少し状況を詳しく教えてください。

モニタ１(スケーリング125%)とモニタ２(スケーリング100%)のどちらがメインでしょうか?

モニタ１とモニタ２は、どのように配置されていますでしょうか? モニタ１が左側、モニタ２が右側でしょうか?

ご質問と、その後のコメントの内容で書き方が変更されているため、私は少々混乱しております。こちらで再現するため、同一の現象についてのみ、正確に書いていただけると幸いです。

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます、左下は右下の間違いです。
モニタ1：左側：メイン：解像度2560x1440をスケール125で設定：DisplayPort接続
モニタ2：右側：解像度1920x1200をスケール100で設定：HDMI接続
となります。
Windows10はバージョン2004(OSビルド19041.330)でいつも基本的にアップデートはしております。
今の前のバージョン（正確なバージョンは見てなかったため情報がありません）でも再現しておりました。

Comment: モニタ１とモニタ２のどちらがメインでしょうか? こちらでは両方試してみましたが、残念ながら問題は再現できませんでした。念のため、[カスタマイズ] の [ウィンドウ] ページをリセットしてお試しください。それでも問題が解決しない場合、大変お手数ですが、次のような手順を行っていただけると幸いです。

1. [ツール] メニューの [インポートとエクスポート] を選択し、[すべての設定をレジストリ ファイルにエクスポート] を選択してください (ただし、ポータブル版の場合は、[すべての設定を INI ファイルにエクスポート] を選択してください)。

2. [ツール] メニューの [すべてのコマンド] - [ツール] - [すべての設定をリセット] を選択します。もし、これで設定がリセットされない場合には、一度、EmEditor をアンインストールし、アンインストールの最中、設定を保存するかどうかの質問には「いいえ」を選択します。そして、再度インストールします。

3. これで問題が解決した場合には、エクスポートしたファイルのすべて (AppData を含む) を zip に圧縮して、私宛 (tech @ emurasoft.com) に送っていただければ幸いです。(エクスポートしたファイルをインポートしていただければ、元の設定に戻ります。)

Comment: [カスタマイズ]の[ウィンドウ]ページとはどちらの設定になりますでしょうか、そちらの方法がわかりましたら試してみます。また左側に設置したモニタ１がメインになります。EmEditorのウィンドウ位置を試していましたが、EmEditorの右側の位置をモニタ１とモニタ２の境界まで（EmEditorのウィンドウの右端をモニタ1の右端に合わせる）広げているときには再現するのですが、モニタ１に配置しているEmEditorのウィンドウの右側をモニタ１端から少し開けると再現しなくなります、数ドット以下の余白にすると再現します。よろしければ再現時のキャプチャをお送りすることも可能です。

Comment: こちらでも現象は再現しました。「モニタ１に配置しているEmEditorのウィンドウの右側をモニタ１端から少し開けると再現しなくなります」で理解できました。しかしWindowsに付属の「メモ帳」でもまったく同じ動作となりますが、この現象ではないでしょうか? そうだとすると、これはWindowsの問題になります。回避策としては、モニター１で作業する場合、ウィンドウの位置とサイズを調整するのではなく、ウィンドウの右上にある最大化ボタンをクリック (またはウィンドウのタイトル バーをダブルクリック) して、ウィンドウをモニター１で最大化してお使いください。[カスタマイズ] の [ウィンドウ] ページは、EmEditorの [ツール] メニューの [カスタマイズ] をクリックして表示されます。

Comment: 確かにメモ帳でも同じ現象が発生しました。Microsoft Excelやエクスプローラ、paint.net、pdicなどでは再現しませんがWindowsの問題もあるのですね。最大化してしまうと他のウィンドウの情報が見えなくなるため右側に隙間を開けるようにします。ありがとうございました。